# Отделение чисел и знаков в строке

Tags: c#

Задача:
Написать калькулятор выражений.
Есть выражение: `3+6/87*120`.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы у меня получился строковый массив:
`["3", "+", "6", "/", "87", "*", "120"]`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял что к Вам приходит строка с выражением?

Comment: Если строка, то я бы создал новый масив, потом читал строку в цикле посимвольно и записывал цифры в новую строку до момента нахождения ключевых мат.символов. При нахождении таких добавлял сформированую строку в массив и следом добавлял в масив мат.символ. Далее продолжать до конца первичной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правельно понял должно быть так :

на входе :  `string a = "3+6/87*120-100";`
на выходе: ["3", "+", "6", "/", "87", "*", "120","-","100"]

сам код :

```
public string[] GetArr(string str)
    {
        var s = str.Split(new[] { '+', '/', '*', '-' });

        int size = s.Length + s.Length - 1;
        string[] arr = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.Length; i++, j = j + 2)
        {
            arr[j] = s[i];
            if (i != s.Length - 1)
            {
                int index = str.IndexOf(s[i], StringComparison.Ordinal);
                index = index + s[i].Length;
                arr[j + 1] = str[index].ToString();
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Как-то неэффективно. Не думаю, что будет работать при наличии унарных операторов. Ну и с пробелами тоже есть сомнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Причем тут пробелы? и унарные операции ? прочитайте сначала вопрос перед тем как писать комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/jB9MFt

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var s = "3+6/87*120";
    var tokens = Regex.Matches(s, @"[-+/*]|\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", tokens));
  }
}
```